# Violation of primary key error in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am doing a backup where upon clicking on the backup button, the data in `Teachers` table will be inserted into the `bkTeachers` table. I'm using this statement below for the rest of my tables however only this particular `Teachers` table causes this error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_bkTeachers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.bkTeachers'.

Code:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO bkTeachers(Teacher_Id, Teacher_Name, Password) Select Teacher_Id, Teacher_Name, Password FROM Teachers WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.bkTeachers  WHERE dbo.bkTeachers.Teacher_Id = dbo.Teachers.Teacher_Id AND bkTeachers.Teacher_Name = Teachers.Teacher_Name  AND bkTeachers.Password = Teachers.Password)", conn);
System.Data.DataSet ds2 = new System.Data.DataSet();
da.Fill(ds2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO bkTeachers(Teacher_Id, Teacher_Name,Password) 
Select Teacher_Id, Teacher_Name,Password FROM Teachers t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.bkTeachers  bk
WHERE bk.Teacher_Id = t.Teacher_Id 
AND bk.Teacher_Name = t.Teacher_Name  
AND bk.Password = t.Password)
```

Try this. Please verify your other query as well. If still not working, check your table to see what is the primary key for it, might be > 3

Comment: @user3566871, check what column is mark as primary key for 'PK_bkTeachers', perhaps more than 3 column. run the selection part of the query and see which data get duplicated

Select Teacher_Id, Teacher_Name,Password FROM Teachers t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.bkTeachers  bk
WHERE bk.Teacher_Id = t.Teacher_Id 
AND bk.Teacher_Name = t.Teacher_Name  
AND bk.Password = t.Password)

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue as there is already an entry with the primary key in the backup table. For example let's assume that Teacher_Id is the PK in the table. First time when you back up the table there will be no error, however the second time you try to back up the Teacher_Id's are already present in the backup table. And this will throw the error you are facing.

You can look to drop the backup table before you backup if you are only interested in the latest snapshot of the Teachers table otherwise you need to add the check if the rows you are trying to backup are not already present in the backup table.

Comment: Yes, exactly. However, that statement i used, i supposed allows me to filter the data. For example, if i have 40 rows in Teachers table, and only 38 rows in bkTeachers, which has already being inserted during previous back up, i want to back up again and insert the two remaining rows into bkTeachers. The problem and funny part is, this statement works for the rest of my tables. Is there anything that i missed out which anyone here can point it out?

Comment: I am assuming that Teacher ID is PK in both the tables. Now say, in the Teachers table a record is updated and user name or password is changed. When you try to backup the Teachers table now you will get 3 rows to be saved in Backup table, two of which will be new rows and one will be updated row.This is because when you filter the rows you use compare the columns between 2 tables using 'and'.